# Setting a custom property of a custom control via mouse click on Form (in DesignMode)

Tags: vb.net, forms, mouse, point, custom-properties

A control of mine has a `List<Point>` as property which needs to be set when that control is constructed. The individual `Point`'s have to be taken from mouse-clicks on the form and it has to happen in the Designmode of Visual Studio.

Now my idea was to open a new Form whenever that control is created which would duplicate the original Form, and on the new Form I could click a bit, register the Points, add them to the List Property and close the new Form when I'm done. But I can't seem to apply the original Forms properties to the new one and I guess it's because it doesn't happen while runtime.

This is what I have so far(I know it ain't much, its about the principle):

Showing a new Form when the control is created:

```
Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim myForm As Form = Me.FindForm()
        Dim newForm As New newForm(myForm)
        scrInput.Show()
    End Sub
```

The new Form:

```
Public Class SourceForm
    Private additionlHeight As Integer = 50

    Public Sub New(ScrSource As Form)
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.Height = ScrSource.Height + additionlHeight
        Me.Width = ScrSource.Width
        Me.BackColor = ScrSource.BackColor
    End Sub
End Class
```

No updated height, width or background color to be seen on the new form... Any idea?

Comment: Try `Me.Refresh()` after setting Height, Width and BackColor. If this still doesn´t work add `Application.DoEvents()`. Or add a class variable `ScrSource` in your SoruceForm and set it in the constructor. But instead of adjusting the properties in the constrcutor, set Height, Width, and BackColor in the `Load` event of the SoruceForm.

Comment: First, that looks like a UserControl not a custom control.  If you properly define the `List(Of Point)` property, VS/IDE will fire off the collection editor for you.

Comment: @ Alex B. did all you suggested but it still doesn't work.

@ Plutonix Sorry, I wasn't aware there is a difference between the two. It does indeed show me the collection editor, but that editor doesn't accomplish what i need (registering points per mouseclick).

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation's sake:

Looks like I managed to solve my problem. I tried many different things, but I believe that creating the new `Form` in the `Load event` of the `control` solved it in the end. The `Refresh()` methode helped as well.

So here is the working code. For the control:

```
Private Sub myControl_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim myForm As Form = Me.FindForm()
        Dim controlInputForm As New myControlInputForm(myForm)
        controlInputForm.Show()
End Sub
```

For the new Form class:

```
Public Class myControlInputForm

        Private additionlHeight As Integer = 50
        Private sourceForm As Form

        Public Sub New(sourceForm As Form)
            InitializeComponent()

            Me.sourceForm = sourceForm

            Me.Height = Me.sourceForm.Height + additionlHeight
            Me.Width = Me.sourceForm.Width
            Me.BackColor = Me.sourceForm.BackColor

            Me.Refresh()
        End Sub 
End Class
```

EDIT: typing errors.